# "Error: ' ' is not a valid resource name character" after updating to Android Gradle 3.0.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

After updating to **`Android gradle plugin 3.0.0`** and `gradle 4.1`, I can't compile my code. The project runs just fine in 2.3.3.

Here is the error when I run gradle with `--stacktrace`:

> Error:com.android.builder.symbols.ResourceDirectoryParseException:
>   Failed to parse XML resource file
>   '/Users/felipea/Documents/next-components/nextcomponents/build/intermediates/bundles/debug/res/values/values.xml'
>   Error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: ' ' is not a valid
>   resource name character Error:Error: ' ' is not a valid resource name
>   character

But I did not found a space character in my values.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="months_of_year">
        <item>JANEIRO</item>
        <item>FEVEREIRO</item>
        <item>MARÇO</item>
        <item>ABRIL</item>
        <item>MAIO</item>
        <item>JUNHO</item>
        <item>JULHO</item>
        <item>AGOSTO</item>
        <item>SETEMBRO</item>
        <item>OUTUBRO</item>
        <item>NOVEMBRO</item>
        <item>DEZEMBRO</item>
    </string-array>
    <attr format="boolean" name="autoSpace"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="calendarDaysOfWeekListStyle"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="calendarItemStyle"/>
    <attr format="color" name="calendarSelectedDayColor"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="calendarStyle"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="calendarTextHeaderStyle"/>
    <attr format="color" name="calendarUnselectedDayColor"/>
    <attr format="integer" name="circumference"/>
    <attr format="integer" name="dividerColor"/>
    <attr format="boolean" name="hasImageInfo"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="imageInfoDrawable"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="tollBarCheckIcon"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="tollBarCloseIcon"/>
    <color name="color_edittext_error">#ff3333</color>
    <color name="green_light">#01ff5f</color>
    <color name="next_black_1">#000000</color>
    <color name="next_black_1_10">#1A000000</color>
    <color name="next_black_2">#1e1e1e</color>
    <color name="next_black_3">#202020</color>
    <color name="next_black_4">#333333</color>
    <color name="next_gray_1">#585858</color>
    <color name="next_gray_2">#808285</color>
    <color name="next_gray_3">#B8B8B8</color>
    <color name="next_gray_4">#E9E9E9</color>
    <color name="next_gray_5">#EFEFEF</color>
    <color name="next_gray_6">#F5F5F5</color>
    <color name="next_green">#01ff5f</color>
    <color name="next_green_1">#00581B</color>
    <color name="next_green_2">#01B240</color>
    <color name="next_green_3">#01DF53</color>
    <color name="next_green_4">#01F85C</color>
    <color name="next_green_5">#01FF5F</color>
    <color name="next_green_6">#00FFA2</color>
    <color name="next_grey">#E9E9E9</color>
    <color name="next_red_1">#FE7059</color>
    <color name="next_transparent">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="next_white_1">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="next_yellow_1">#CCB80C</color>
    <color name="next_yellow_2">#FFE60F</color>
    <declare-styleable name="AnimatedIcon"><attr format="boolean" name="isDark"/><attr format="color" name="iconStrokeColor"/><attr format="dimension" name="iconStrokeWidth"/></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="MaskableLayout"><attr format="reference" name="mask"/><attr name="porterduffxfermode">
            <enum name="ADD" value="0"/>
            <enum name="CLEAR" value="1"/>
            <enum name="DARKEN " value="2"/>
            <enum name="DST" value="3"/>
            <enum name="DST_ATOP" value="4"/>
            <enum name="DST_IN" value="5"/>
            <enum name="DST_OUT" value="6"/>
            <enum name="DST_OVER" value="7"/>
            <enum name="LIGHTEN" value="8"/>
            <enum name="MULTIPLY" value="9"/>
            <enum name="OVERLAY" value="10"/>
            <enum name="SCREEN" value="11"/>
            <enum name="SRC" value="12"/>
            <enum name="SRC_ATOP" value="13"/>
            <enum name="SRC_IN" value="14"/>
            <enum name="SRC_OUT" value="15"/>
            <enum name="SRC_OVER" value="16"/>
            <enum name="XOR" value="17"/>
        </attr><attr format="boolean" name="anti_aliasing"/></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="NextBaseEditText"><attr format="boolean" name="upper_case"/><attr format="boolean" name="block_special_char"/><attr format="boolean" name="allow_email_char"/><attr format="boolean" name="block_numbers"/><attr name="android:text"/><attr format="boolean" name="error_enabled"/><attr name="android:hint"/><attr name="android:textSize"/><attr name="android:maxLines"/><attr format="string" name="fontType"/><attr name="android:maxLength"/><attr name="android:textColor"/><attr format="reference" name="textColorHint"/><attr format="reference" name="til_style"/><attr name="android:textAllCaps"/><attr format="boolean" name="optional"/></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="NextCalendarView"><attr format="color" name="textColor"/><attr format="color" name="textSelectedColor"/><attr format="color" name="selectedColor"/></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="NextCheckBox"><attr format="string" name="key"/><attr name="android:text"/><attr format="color" name="squareStrokeColor"/><attr name="android:textColor"/></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="NextCheckablePageIndicator"><attr format="color" name="strokeLineColor"/><attr format="color" name="checkedStrokeLineColor"/><attr format="color" name="checkImageColor"/><attr format="color" name="dotColor"/></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="NextDatePickerButton"><attr format="enum" name="calendar_tipe">
            <enum name="android" value="0"/>
            <enum name="next" value="1"/>
        </attr><attr format="string" name="date_patern"/><attr format="enum" name="calendar_swipe_orientation">
            <enum name="horizontal" value="0"/>
            <enum name="vertical" value="1"/>
        </attr><attr format="string" name="calendar_title"/></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="NextFlowView"><attr format="dimension" name="flowStrokeWidth"/></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="NextForm"><attr format="boolean" name="validateOnStart"/><attr format="boolean" name="editable"/><attr format="boolean" name="multilevelData"/><attr format="string" name="titleHeader"/><attr format="color" name="titleHeaderColor"/><attr name="android:paddingLeft"/><attr name="android:paddingRight"/><attr name="android:paddingBottom"/><attr name="android:paddingTop"/></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="NextFormExpandableSubForm"><attr name="android:text"/><attr format="boolean" name="expanded"/><attr format="boolean" name="subFormBottomLineVisible"/></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="NextFormItemContainer"><attr format="boolean" name="disableable"/><attr format="boolean" name="required"/><attr format="string" name="invalidMessage"/><attr format="string" name="emptyMessage"/><attr format="string" name="placeholder"/><attr format="string" name="fieldName"/><attr format="color" name="placeholderColor"/><attr format="float" name="placeholderAlpha"/><attr format="boolean" name="bottomLineVisible"/><attr format="color" name="bottomLineColor"/><attr name="android:enabled"/><attr name="autoSpace"/><attr name="hasImageInfo"/><attr name="imageInfoDrawable"/></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="NextFormSubFormList"><attr format="reference" name="subFormLayout"/></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="NextPicker"><attr format="color|reference" name="solidColor"/><attr format="reference" name="selectionBackground"/><attr format="reference" name="selectionDivider"/><attr format="dimension" name="selectionDividerHeight"/><attr format="dimension" name="selectionDividersDistance"/><attr format="dimension" name="internalMinHeight"/><attr format="dimension" name="internalMaxHeight"/><attr format="dimension" name="internalMinWidth"/><attr format="dimension" name="internalMaxWidth"/><attr format="reference" name="internalLayout"/><attr format="reference" name="virtualButtonPressedDrawable"/><attr format="reference" name="NextPickerStyle"/></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="NextPickerButton"><attr format="string" name="blankText"/><attr name="android:textColor"/><attr format="reference" name="pickerDrawable"/><attr format="color" name="pickerDrawableColor"/></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="NextRadioButton"><attr name="android:checked"/><attr format="string" name="value"/><attr name="android:text"/><attr name="android:textColor"/><attr format="color" name="circleStrokeColor"/><attr format="string" name="textTop"/><attr format="string" name="textBottom"/><attr name="android:orientation"/><attr format="boolean" name="multiCheck"/></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="NextSmileView"><attr format="color" name="smileStrokeColor"/></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="NextSquaredGraphView"><attr format="dimension" name="strokeWidth"/><attr format="dimension" name="cornerRadius"/><attr format="color" name="backStrokeColor"/></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="NextSwitchButton"><attr format="string" name="keySwitcher"/><attr name="android:text"/><attr name="android:textColor"/><attr name="hasImageInfo"/><attr name="imageInfoDrawable"/><attr name="autoSpace"/></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="NextTextView"><attr format="enum" name="NextFontType">
            <enum name="newjune_medium" value="1"/>
            <enum name="newjune_semibold" value="2"/>
            <enum name="newjune_book" value="3"/>
        </attr></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="NextTitleSession"><attr name="android:text"/><attr name="android:textColor"/></declare-styleable>
    <dimen name="default_padding">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="horizontal_indicator_corner">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_animated_icon_height">24dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_animated_icon_width">24dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_checkbox_icon_apply_size">24dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_checkbox_square_border_size">48dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_checkbox_square_container_size">48dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_edittext_font_size">15sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_expandable_title_text_size">10sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_form_header_height">154dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_form_header_padding_top">36dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_form_header_text_title_size">15sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_item_auto_margin_bottom">20dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_item_container_error_message_font_size">10sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_item_container_placeholder_font_size">10sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_page_indicator_dot">5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_page_indicator_dot_margin">4dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_picker_button_text_size">15sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_radio_button_circle_container_size">70dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_radio_button_circle_margin">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_radio_button_green_circle_size">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_radio_button_grey_circle_size">52dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_radio_button_text_font_size">15sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_radio_button_text_footer_font_size">10sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_radio_button_text_header_font_size">10sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_radio_button_text_margin">12dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_radio_button_vertical_width">135dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_switch_button_layout_height">54dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_switch_button_text_margin">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_switch_button_text_size">15sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_switch_button_view_size">48dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="next_title_session_text_size">10sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="period_picker_corner">26dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="period_picker_corner_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="period_picker_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="period_picker_vertical_margin">10dp</dimen>
    <item name="np__decrement" type="id"/>
    <item name="np__increment" type="id"/>
    <string name="add">+ Adicionar</string>
    <string name="agendar">AGENDAR</string>
    <string name="app_name">NextComponents</string>
    <string name="date_patern_expanded_br">dd/MM/yyyy</string>
    <string name="date_patern_short_br">dd/MM/yy</string>
    <string name="datepickerdialog_calendar">Calendário</string>
    <string name="default_blank_message">deve ser preenchido</string>
    <string name="default_invalid_message">Inválido</string>
    <string name="friday_prefix">S</string>
    <string name="monday_prefix">S</string>
    <string name="optional">Opcional</string>
    <string name="picker_default_text">Selecione</string>
    <string name="receipts_period">%1$s até %2$s</string>
    <string name="receipts_period_end_date_invalid">A data final deve ser menor que a data atual</string>
    <string name="receipts_period_period_title">PERÍODO</string>
    <string name="receipts_period_start_date_invalid">A data inicial deve ser menor que a data atual</string>
    <string name="remove">- Remover</string>
    <string name="saturday_prefix">S</string>
    <string name="sunday_prefix">D</string>
    <string name="tag_ico">ico</string>
    <string name="text_date_end">Data final</string>
    <string name="text_date_start">Data inicial</string>
    <string name="text_title_calendar">Calendário</string>
    <string name="thursday_prefix">Q</string>
    <string name="title_header_example">New June Book 15 pt\nLorem Ipsum dolor sit\namet, consectetur.</string>
    <string name="tuesday_prefix">T</string>
    <string name="wednesday_prefix">Q</string>
    <style name="AnimatedIconToolbar">
        <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/next_animated_icon_width</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/next_animated_icon_height</item>
    </style>
    <style name="CustomPicker">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearance</item>
        <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
        <item name="android:fadingEdge">none</item>
        <item name="android:fadingEdgeLength">0dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="DialogAnimations">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_down</item>
    </style>
    <style name="GreenPicker" parent="CustomPicker">
        <item name="solidColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="selectionBackground">@color/next_green_6</item>
        <item name="internalLayout">@layout/next_number_picker_with_selector</item>
        <item name="internalMinWidth">64dip</item>
        <item name="internalMaxHeight">200dp</item>
        <item name="internalMinHeight">200dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextButton">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">55dp</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
        <item name="NextFontType">newjune_book</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextButtonBlack" parent="NextButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/next_background_text_button_black</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/next_background_button_black</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextButtonGreen" parent="NextButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/next_background_text_button_green</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/next_background_button_green</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextButtonWhite" parent="NextButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/next_background_text_button_white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/next_background_button_white</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextCalendarDayListDark">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/next_black_1</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextCalendarDayOfWeekInitials" parent="NextCalendarStyle">
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextCalendarItemDark">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/next_gray_2</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextCalendarStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/next_black_1</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextCalendarStyleBlack">
        <item name="android:background">@color/next_green_4</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/next_black_1</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="calendarTextHeaderStyle">@style/NextCalendarTextHeaderDark</item>
        <item name="calendarItemStyle">@style/NextCalendarItemDark</item>
        <item name="calendarDaysOfWeekListStyle">@style/NextCalendarDayListDark</item>
        <item name="calendarSelectedDayColor">@color/next_white_1</item>
        <item name="calendarUnselectedDayColor">@color/next_black_1</item>
        <item name="dividerColor">@color/next_green_3</item>
        <item name="circumference">@drawable/circumference_green</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextCalendarTextHeaderDark">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/next_black_1</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextCheckBox">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/next_black_1</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextCheckBoxDark">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/next_gray_6</item>
        <item name="squareStrokeColor">@color/next_gray_1</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextCheckablePageIndicator">
        <item name="strokeLineColor">@color/next_gray_2</item>
        <item name="checkedStrokeLineColor">@color/next_green</item>
        <item name="checkImageColor">@color/next_black_1</item>
        <item name="dotColor">@color/next_gray_2</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextEditText">
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/next_edittext_font_size</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextEditTextDark" parent="NextEditText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/next_gray_6</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextEditTextLight" parent="NextEditText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/next_black_1</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextErrorInputStyle" parent="NextNormalInputStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_edittext_error</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextForm">
        <item name="android:background">@color/next_gray_6</item>
        <item name="titleHeaderColor">@color/next_gray_3</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextFormDark">
        <item name="android:background">@color/next_black_1</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextFormItemContainer">
        <item name="placeholderColor">@color/next_black_1</item>
        <item name="placeholderAlpha">0.3</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextFormItemContainerDark">
        <item name="placeholderColor">@color/next_white_1</item>
        <item name="placeholderAlpha">0.5</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextFormSeparatorLineLight">
        <item name="android:alpha">0.6</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/next_black_1</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextFormTextItemContainerLight" parent="NextFormItemContainer">
        <item name="bottomLineVisible">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextFullScreenDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_down</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextNormalInputStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    </style>
    <style name="NextPickerButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/next_black_1</item>
        <item name="pickerDrawableColor">@color/next_black_1</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextPickerButtonDark">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/next_white_1</item>
        <item name="pickerDrawableColor">@color/next_white_1</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextRadioButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/next_black_1</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextRadioButtonDark">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/next_gray_6</item>
        <item name="circleStrokeColor">@color/next_gray_1</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextSwitchButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/next_black_1</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextTextLabel">
        <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE stateCd -->
        <item name="android:textColorHint">#8d8d8d</item>
        <!-- Label color in TRUE stateCd and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#01ff54</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#313131</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#666666</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="NextFontType">newjune_semibold</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextThemeDark" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/next_white_1</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/next_black_1</item>
        <item name="calendarStyle">@style/NextCalendarStyleBlack</item>
        <item name="tollBarCloseIcon">@drawable/ic_close_black</item>
        <item name="tollBarCheckIcon">@drawable/ic_check_black</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NextTitleSession">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/next_gray_2</item>
    </style>
    <style name="TextLabelWhite">
        <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE stateCd -->
        <item name="android:textColorHint">#FFFFFF</item>
        <!-- Label color in TRUE stateCd and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#01ff54</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="NextFontType">newjune_semibold</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**EDIT: My gradle files**

#### *gradle-wrapper.properties*

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

#### *top-level build.gradle* - project build gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

#### *app build.gradle* - my lib demo app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myappid"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':nextcomponents')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

#### *components build.gradle* - my lib

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1"
    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0"
    compile "com.android.support:design:27.0.1"
    compile 'com.intellij:annotations:12.0@jar'
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:1.5.3'
    compile 'com.github.rubensousa:gravitysnaphelper:1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.keyframes:keyframes:1.0'
}
```

Comment: You added the wrong file. That is the one generated from the build, add the ones that are in your folders manually. When the build fails, the merged values xml file can be off in terms of the actual content of the files

Comment: Try to clean your project and rebuild it, or remove manually `/intermediates/` folder

Comment: Zoe: this is the file that appears on the error. My project don't have a values.xml file, I have colors.xml, dimen.xml, etc on the project's values folder. I don't understand why the same files compile on 2.3.3 but not on 3.0.0. there is some config I miss on the migration?

Comment: akhilesh: Already did it. I tried removing all idea related files (*.iml, build folders and .idea folder) and importing the project again, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `DARKEN` enum has a space in it:

```
<enum name="DARKEN " value="2"/>
```

I found this by running your question thru egrep:

```
egrep 'name="[^"]* [^"]*"'
```

This seems to be a problem in a library you're using: https://github.com/christophesmet/android_maskable_layout/blob/43b109a/library/src/main/res/values/attrs_maskable_framelayout.xml

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. I fixed it in the latest release v1.1.0
compile 'com.github.christophesmet:android_maskable_layout:v1.1.0'